# How can i get all k8s resouce in namespace by using go client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

i'm using go client as client to communicate with k8s api server.
I want a result similar to the following command .

```
kubectl get all -n kontrol-migration-helper -o json
```

I hoped that the code below would output all the resources below the namespace, but it did not work as expected.

```
func (srv *Service) GetAllResouce(projectName string) (interface{}, error) {
    projectDatas, err := srv.client.CoreV1().Namespaces().Get(context.TODO(), projectName, v1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return projectDatas, nil
}
```

what should i do?

I'm referring to the [document of the go client](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#pkg-index), but it's too hard to find what I want.

Comment: Fyi.. `kubectl get all` does not return true list of **all** the resources in the namespace.

Comment: `kubectl api-resources` would list the resource name and it may be iterated. You may be already aware of this, or not worth for your use case. Just fyi

Comment: @P.... oh... I was mistaken.
All resources would be good, but I am satisfied with the output from the command I described.

Comment: Maybe your best bet to use resapi ?
similar to:
 err := c.restClient.AbsPath("/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1").Get().Namespace(namespace).Resource("pods").Do(context.Background()).Into(&result)